# Set default value for multiple table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, triggers

I have a database with column ( empid ) in multiple tables.

I want to make a trigger or function or stored procedures to set a default value for this column in all tables after insert

Comment: Add a default constraint in each table.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73277/set-default-value-for-all-columns-with-specific-name-within-a-database

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will resolve your Answer or give you some insight what we need to put in function or stored procedure to resolve the issue.

SELECT
   'alter ' + TABLE_Schema + '.' + Table_name + 'ADD  CONSTRAINT constraint_Name
 DEFAULT (22) FOR [Column]'

FROM
   db_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
   COLUMN_NAME = 'ID'